# Is it possible to collapse through left and right margins with a parent element?

Tags: css, margin

I'd like to collapse the left and right margins of a block through its parent.

I cannot change the style of the child, because its margin is unknown. It can be anything. I want the parent's background to not show in the area of the child's margins. Vertical margins behave this way, and I want to find a way to make horizontal margins behave this way.

For example (I'd like the red not to be visible at all):

```css
.a {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.b { 
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

According to the docs, left/right margin collapse through only happens if block-progression is lr or rl (which isn't really a thing browsers support it seems).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Is there another way?

Comment: No you can't do that and it be wrong even if you achieve that somehow.Making the child div's width 100% would collapse the right margin but that's wrong and can you specify what are you trying to do exactly or asked just for information ?

Comment: It wouldn't be wrong if it's what I want. It's something the spec supports but browsers don't implement. What I want it for is to put a background color *behind* an element whose margin size I do not know. I do not want the background color to show through the margins. The fiddle I gave demonstrates this. I want the red to be hidden. (imagine that the blue square was actually a transparent png, or had some text, etc.